# I try to change redirection 301

Tags: redirect, http-status-code-301, vhosts

In the website of my client, there is this vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName website.com
  ServerAlias *.website.com
  Redirect 301 / https://www.newwebsite.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

I want to change the redirection 301 to redirect to nothing.

When I updated the vhost. Nothing change when I restart the server.

Someone can help me ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Create a blank web page.

Redirect to that page:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName website.com
  ServerAlias *.website.com
  Redirect 301 / https://website.com/blank.html
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I haven't looked in the right place. The redirection was on the  IAP's administration. Thanks a lot for your advice.